# How to change owner of Microsoft Teams app?

Tags: microsoft-teams

One of my coworkers created a bot with Microsoft Bot Framework and we started to use it as an organization app. He created the manifest in his teams account within App Studio. I'll continue to work on that bot, so i want to see the app in my App Studio manifest editor. How can we change the owner of the app without changing app id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the coworker is still around, then inside App Studio there is an option to Download the manifest. In your own App Studio instance, there's an option then to "upload" a manifest. Just for information, the app can be in both of your App Studios at the same time, because having it there is not really registering it in Teams or anything like that.

Ideally, to really use it inside your organisation, you should deploy it to your internal company catalog properly, so that it is visible more widely, can be upgraded independently, etc., rather than using App Studio to deploy, for exactly the reasons you're running into. To do that, inside the "App store" there's an option on bottom of the left menu to upload for the entire company.